# Back button goes to tags instead of questions about a selected tag

Tags: bug, android-app

How to reproduce:

1. Search by tags.
2. Select arbitrary tag.
3. Select arbitrary question
4. Go back (either navigation button or phone button)
5. Expected: get back to tag search results (questions list). Actual behavior: getting back to tags.

Nexus 5

Android 6.0.1

App version 1.0.83